# when I do print(nxtlines) why print starts from rhrhrhr PM-HR-PC(at character 111) and not after PM-HR-PC(at character 128)

Tags: python-3.x

```
    import openpyxl 
    import os
    import re
    os.chdir('C:\\Users\\Rakesh Kumar\\Desktop') 
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')
    sheet = wb['test']
    c=sheet['G29'].value    
    with open("test.txt","r") as f:
        lines = f.read().rstrip()   
        match = re.search(str(c), str(lines))
        if match:
            print (c)
            t= match.end(0)
        i = f.seek(t+1)
        nxtlines = f.readline()    
        print(nxtlines)
        print(i)
        print(t)
```

> *****************************output****************************************
>
> PM-HR-PC
>
> rhrhrhr PM-HR-PC
>
> 129
>
> 128
>
> **********************test.txt***********************************************
>
> dsfsdffsfsd
>
> fsdfs
>
> sdfsfs
>
> dfdsfsdf
>
> sfsdf
>
> sdfsd
>
> sfsf
>
> sf
>
> sf
>
> s
>
> sfs
>
> fs
>
> fsd
>
> fsdfsdfsfsdfs
>
> sdfs
>
> fsdfsdfergretgrghjt
>
> hr
>
> rhrhrhr PM-HR-PC
>
> host
>
> host
>
> host
>
> **********************************example.xlxs********************************
>
> Coloum G29 is "PM-HR-PC"

Comment: what is the logic of the script?

Comment: Read a column in excel, search the value in text.txt, if found print next few lines until some condition is met.

Comment: if you would like some help.. you better lay out the logic in a clearer way...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reading your lines into a big string and matching against it `lines = f.read().rstrip()`, try directly iterating over the lines and matching against each one.

```
with open(path) as fh:
    for line in fh.read().splitlines():
        if re.match(REGEX, line):
            function(line)
```